# Vector parallel and distinct

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Equation 1:
$$x=3-t\ ,\ y=2t\ ,\ z=2-3t$$
Equation 2:
$$x=3+s\ ,\ y=-3-2s\ ,\ z=6+3s$$

Now I proved that they are distinct by showing that the system does not have a solution.
But how am I supposed to prove that they are parallel when I can't get them to be multiples of each other since they are different variables.

Also, how can I find the equation of a unique plane that contains both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Calculate $x-x_0$ and so on, where the $0$ subscript means it's the constant term:
   $$x-3=-t, y=2t, z-2=-3t\\x-3=s, y+3=-2s, z-6=3s$$
   Now plug in $s=-t$
2. Write equation of a plane given by a line and a point. Take line given by equation 1, and then take **any** point on line 2. You can choose $s=0$, but you don't have to.

Comment: I'm so dumb I had already solved the first part and I was staring right at the answer. Thank you!